# How to run Docker on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I followed the [official instructions on how to install Docker on Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/), added my account to the "docker" group and rebooted the computer, and I'm not able to run "docker" (not even as root) as I get the following error:

```
$ sudo docker info
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

However, I realized that if from another session I run "sudo docker -d", then Docker will work just fine, even without using "sudo".

What’s the best way to fix this? I guess this issue is related to the service script, but I'm surprised that I couldn't find instructions or even other people finding the same issue.

Comment: Is your Docker service running? Try `service docker status` and `service docker start` if it's not running. Maybe your init system is not configured to start the Docker service on boot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To make the Docker daemon run at boot on 15.04, you can run:

`systemctl enable docker`

I guess they will soon update the get.docker.com script when more people complain about this, see also https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12002#issuecomment-106759295

You can also run `systemctl is-enabled docker` to see if it's currently enabled or not.

Comment: Interesting feedback, more precise than my answer. +1

Comment: Shouldn't it be `systemctl enable docker`?

Comment: Indeed @LuRsT, thanks! I edited my post to correct this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [similar issue (11989)](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/11989), which says:

It could be a problem related to docker daemon not automatically starting under certain Ubuntu versions (`cat /etc/lsb-release`). [See #12002](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12002) for an example.

> Is the daemon running?

```
sudo service docker status
```

[Issue 12002](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12002) illustrates the issue even for Ubuntu 15.04:

> I need to sudo service docker restart after every reboot
>   I'm having the same issue on Ubuntu 15.04.
>   After "`sudo service docker restart`" it starts working.